# Rotation around Y affect another AXIS

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, unityscript

today, I have huge problem with rotating camera in unity3d.

This code should rotate camera around Y axis right?

```
var rotSpeed = 5;

if(Input.GetKey("q")){
    this.transform.Rotate(0, -rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
if(Input.GetKey("e")){
    this.transform.Rotate(0, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

But I is affecting another AXIS too! When I press Q or E, X and Z axis are changing too, but why?

Thank you, for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the same behavior with

```
transform.Rotate(0,  -rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, Space.World);
```

and

```
transform.Rotate(0,  -rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

?

Also, are you seeing incorrect movement of the object, or just surprising numbers in the editor with correct behavior?

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to post solution when I went to sleep.
I solved it by adding this 'Space.World' yeah. But also I made it like this 'this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);'